# TCL hash wildcard usage?

Tags: tcl

Assume we have a 2D hash.

```
set a(1,x) abc
set a(2,x) def
```

Now I want to know if 'x' exists in both.
I can do :

```
info exists a(1,x) && info exists a(2,x)
```

I can put this into a loop but that starts to look clunky.

Is there a way to wildcard ? This naive idea obviously doesn't work.

```
info exists a(*,x)
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`array names`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm) command here:

```
set all_names [array names a]
set x_names [array names a "*,x"]    ;# quotes not strictly required here

if {[llength $all_names] == [llength $x_names]} {
    puts "all array keys have x"
} else {
    puts "some array keys don't have x"
}
```

Comment: If searches like this are important, switching to an SQLite database (maybe just an in-memory one) is probably a good idea.